# how to get into minecraft i cant figure out how to start playing

Tags: minecraft

I downloaded minecraft and can't figure out how to start playing it please help.I tried looking at tutorials and they didn't work or got me to a old version where i couldn't update.

Comment: Have you tried [Minecraft Installer Peeps](https://launchpad.net/~minecraft-installer-peeps/+archive/minecraft-installer)? Here you have a guide how to use this PPA: [Easily Install Minecraft In Ubuntu Via PPA Using An Unofficial Minecraft Installer](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/easily-install-minecraft-in-ubuntu-via.html)

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft is a java application:  You should make sure that you java installed, either 6 or 7.  These can be loaded in the Ubuntu software center.

Assuming that you have Java loaded, find the minecraft.jar file in your download directory, right click on it and mark it as 'executable'.  Then right click on the minecraft.jar file and say 'Open'

Minecraft like many games, is dependent upon the graphics subsystem of your computer.  It may play more slowly than you would like, and this can be because of the OpenJDK Java runtimes, or because of the graphics driver in use, or some other issue.  You might find some support here, but you may also need to search the web for minecraft specific forums.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download and install the Oracle Java runtime (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) . Open JDK might work but it may also cause headaches. Instructions are here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java). Then to start you can launch Minecraft from a terminal window. java -jar Minecraft.jar You can also create a shell script to execute that command in a shortcut. That is what I do for my kids to play.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of installing and playing Minecraft doesn't involve downloading the jar. Open up a terminal CTRL + ALT + T . Then paste in the following lines: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer` `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer` . This will instal Open-JDK as well as Minecraft, it comes with a nifty launcher which you can use from the Dash or by pinning it to the Launcher.